# stored procedure using java script object ( sql, express, react)

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a java script object which when ran in console.info displays as below

```
[
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the keyboard separate from the screen?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'Question declined But not a problem',
[0]     question: 'Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'gfkjkh',
[0]     question: 'Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?',
[0]     state: 'problem specified'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the keyboard separate from the screen?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Does the keyboard tilt?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is it possible to find a comfortable typing postion?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Do you have a good keyboard technique?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Are the characters on the keyboard clear and readable?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: "Is your mouse or other pointing device suitable to the task you're using it for?",
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the mouse (or other pointing device) located sufficently close to you?  ',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is there support for your wrist and forearm when using the mouse(or other pointing device)',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Does the mouse (or other pointing device) work smoothly at a speed that suits you?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Can you easily adjust the software settings for speed and accuracy of the pointer?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Are the characters on your screen clear and readable?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the text size on your screen confortable to read?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the image on your screen free from flicker and jitter?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: "Is your screen's specification suitable for its intended use?",
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     answer: 'yes',
[0]     question: 'Is the brightness and/or contrast on your screen adjustable?',
[0]     state: 'Accepted'
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

I am passing this through  to a sql stored procedure to insert into a table.Below is the stored procedure I have.

```
alter procedure StoreAnswers 

@Results nvarchar(500)
as
 begin
  insert into QuestionResponses(QuestionResponse, QuestionWhenAnswered)
         select substring(value, charindex('{answer: "', value) + 10,  charindex('", ', value, charindex('{answer: "', value) + 10) -  charindex('{answer: "', value) - 10) as QuestionResponse, 
                substring(value, charindex('question: "', value) + 11, charindex('", ', value, charindex('question: "', value) + 11) - charindex('question: "', value) - 11) as QuestionWhenAnswered

         from string_split(@Results, char(10))    
end;
```

However this does not work. Is there an easy way in that I can modify this to make it work with the javascript object I have shown above.

At the moment it is throwing the error.

```
RequestError: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Any help is much appreciated !!

EDIT ---

```
app.post("/post-question-answers", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("!called");
  try {
    let results = req.body.results;

    console.info(results);

    await sql.connect(config, function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // create Request object
      var request = new sql.Request();
      request.input("Results", sql.VarChar, results);
      // query to the database and get the records
      request.execute("dbo.StoreAnswers", function(err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // send records as a response
        res.json(recordset);
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.info(e);
  }
  res.statusCode = 400;
  res.statusMessage = "bad request";
  // res.json({ message: "Email Missing" });
});
```

Comment: Hy, is it really necessary to solve this task with a sql-procedure? I would recommend to write a short program in any common language to parse your json file and insert the different entrys of this array with this software.

Comment: It seems the most practical otherwise I would need to break these up into separate variables to pass through to my stored procedure.

Comment: How else could I tackle this ?

Comment: Is your object really formatted as above? Maybe you have a problem with the characters:  
 In your stored procedure you search with the seperator: "  
Your file uses mostly the seperator: '
In one question your file uses the seperator: "

Is this just a typo in your question or maybe a part of the real problem?

Comment: Yep thats the console.log of this array of objects

Comment: any idea on how to modifiy this to work

Comment: or any simpler ways to do so ?

Comment: Like I said before, I would prefer to solve this not in SQL.
How does you stored procedure get started? If you use something like npm, you could iterate your array and insert any item itself with the 3 variables. This would be much easier and would had less problems in daily use...

Comment: I have updated the question to show hwo my express is using it

Comment: Is there a way I can break it down form there ? It would be easier to have this split down before but I am not sure how to do this and then iterate them through my stored procedure.